# Why spoj is giving Wrong Answer for this solution of "Power of Integer"?

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to solve [INTEGER1](http://www.spoj.com/SPOJ/problems/INTEGER1/) problem on spoj. My approach is very simple. It first calculates x(x^i=n) for all power of from 2 to 63. It then removes all the duplicates and then finally adds up the powers. But its is giving me wrong answer on spoj. 
I have tried it on Ideone and my machine for many use cases but it is giving me correct result.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned long long int a,b,result;
    unsigned long long int power[65],temp;
    int i,j;

    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%lld",&a);
        scanf("%lld",&b);
        if(a==0)
            break;
        result=0;
        power[0]=0;
        power[1]=b-a+1;

        a--;
        for(i=2;i<64;i++)
        {
            power[i]=floor(pow((long double)b,(long double)1/i));
            while(pow((power[i]-1),(long double)i)>=b)
            {
                power[i]--;
            }
            while(pow((power[i]+1),(long double)i)<=b)
            {
                power[i]++;
            }

            temp=floor(pow((long double)a,(long double)1/i));
            while(pow((temp-1),(long double)i)>=a)
            {
                temp--;
            }
            while(pow((temp+1),(long double)i)<=a)
            {
                temp++;
            }
            power[i]-=temp;
        }
        for(i=63;i>=1;i--)
        {
            for(j=i*2;j<64;j=j+i)
            {
                power[i]-=power[j];
            }
        }
        for(i=1;i<64;i++)
        {
            result+=i*power[i];
        }
        printf("%lld\n",result);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Did you read any of the comments on the challenge? Please also read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @Deduplicator I read but I thought I could use it once for calculating root. But thanks a lot for providing me this useful link. Does it mean that I have to calculate the nth root myself? If so can you please give me link for that also?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm

Comment: @deviantfan I had a look at it. But I have edited my current code to correct the precision error still it's giving me Wrong Answer. Is it because it is overflowing with my new changes? Can you please take a look at the edited code in question?

Comment: @Naman : you are losing precision due to the usage of floating-point arithmetic. This challenge *probably* requires you to implement some kind of custom arbitrary-size arithmetic ("big number" arithmetic).

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar I agree. Can you suggest some method to find integer kth root of a number. I think Newton's method might take a lot time to converge for big numbers like(10^18)

Comment: @Naman : Sorry, I have no idea about numerical algorithms.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: Please re-read. `long long` is plenty big enough for the task.

Comment: If you want to follow the path of finding the kth root the simplest way might be to a) calculate root r using floating point, b) truncate the root to an integer R, c) using 64 bit integers calculate R^k to confirm you aren't being fooled by floating point precision limits.

Comment: `%llu` should be used for scanf with unsigned long long.

Comment: @Penguino I am using the same method but for part c) 64bit integer calculation might overflow. For example, N=10^18 and k=1/59 then N^k=2 but to verify it I need to calculate (2-1)^59 and (2+1)^59 and for second part 64bit int will overflow. Is there any way to cope with it without using arrays?

Answer (score 1):

for the input

```
100 100
10000 100000000
100000000000 100000000000
100000000000000 100000000000000
1000000000000000 1000000000000000
0 0
```

your output is

```
2
100001508
11
14
11
```

but correct output is

```
2
100001508
11
14
15
```

now for finding `kth` root of `a`..doing some mathematics

```
let x = a ^ (1 / k) (^ denotes power NOT XOR)(this is also `kth` root of `a`)
```

taking *natural logarithm* **(ln)** both sides

```
ln x = ln (a ^ (1 / k)) = (1 / k) * ln (a) {property of log}
```

now taking `exponent` both sides

```
exp (ln x) = exp (ln (a) / k)
```

and according to `log` property

```
exp (ln x) = x
```

so we finally get

```
x = exp (ln(a) / k) which is equivalent to `kth` root of `a`
```

here is a function for finding it in `C`

remember in mathematics we use `ln` for finding *natural logarithm* which is equivalent to that of `log` in `C`

```
double kth_root_finder(long long int a, long long int k) {
    if (k == 1) {
         return a;
    }
    if (k == 2) {
         return sqrt(a);
    }
    return exp(log(a) / k);
}
```

**EDIT 1**:-as the OP pointed out, there will be overflow but i don't think so it will happen..consider a case where we have

```
a = 1000000000000000000 and k = 2 (worst case)(ignoring second if condition)
```

then

```
exp(log(1000000000000000000) / 2) = 999999999.999999 = 1000000000(if ceil is taken)
```

[here](http://ideone.com/7BgBk5) is a link for above..
so i don't think there is a chance of `overflow`..if its there please point out..

Comment: I think precision error will come with this method also. Should I use nearest integer or floor for the output of this function?

Comment: Finally I got AC. I used the same pow function to get first estimate of root and then corrected precision error with INT64 calculation. Earlier I was not checking for overflows. SO now my solution checks for overflows with first double calculation then does INT64 calculation. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Naman:- congrats..if it helped you can accept it..i don't think it will overflow

Comment: i had edited my answer..and i don't find a case of overflow..if you find any please point